# If a species developed on an atmosphereless world, would it survive on Earth?

Tags: planets, xenobiology, atmosphere

Would a species which developed on a world with no atmosphere (i.e. the moon) survive on a planet with an atmosphere, such as Earth?

Comment: Waaay not enough info. But probably not, it would be crushed going from vacuum to ~14.7 psi.

Comment: There's too much information missing, since that would depend a lot on the nature of the species.

Answer (score 6):

## It depends on oxygen

The creatures that developed on Earth before there was oxygen were mostly killed in a photosynthesis-inflicted extinction event. The photosynthetic process releases oxygen, and so these first cyanobacteria [added a new element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event) (free oxygen O$_2$) to the atmosphere which had not been there before.

Many of the creatures that developed before this point were not equipped to deal with this highly reactive compound. Oxygen will readily react with many things; mostly notably, in fires. Cells not equipped to be immersed in an oxygen atmosphere would likely have been destroyed as the free oxygen interacted with their cell walls in redox reaction. This is more or less equivalent to being dissolved by acid.

The most likely reason a creature from a atmosphere-less world would *not* survive on Earth is that its biology is incompatible with our oxygen heavy atmosphere. How likely that is, I can't really say for sure, but I would guess that it is very likely that any creature from an anoxic environment would not be able to survive direct exposure to oxygen.

Comment: So, then if this species were to be space-faring, they would *have* to colonize worlds without atmospheres, right?

Comment: @Giaxo17 Or they could wear suits. Humans can't survive on the moon naked, but we've been there, and might even colonize it one day.

Comment: Also, do you know what liquids are, theoretically, able to support life?

Comment: @Giaxo17 Sounds like a topic for a new question!